# .NET Core seed data with dotnet cli

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have searched everywhere and most articles I found suggest that to seed data, I have to use the Program Class which would run my seed data code whenever I run the project.

The issue I'm having is I am setting up a CI\CD pipeline in which I need to run a seed data command before I run the project. Other posts have suggested that I have to build my own dotnet cli package to seed data.

Is there a better solution, I would like a solution similar to laravel's database seeding command `php artisan db:seed`

Comment: Yes, make your own CLI package in your project for database changes. You can run it any time with command line. You can share Entities or other things in your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way I've found to seed data separately from running the application is by using the Main method args:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        if(args.Length > 0){
            bool seed = args.Any(arg => arg == "/seed");
            bool start = args.Any(arg => arg == "/start");

            if(seed) InitializeDatabase(host);
            if(start) host.Run();
        }else{
            InitializeDatabase(host);
            host.Run();
        }
 }
```

So to seed separately from running the run `dotnet run /seed` and to run do `dotnet run /start`. If you do only `dotnet run` then it will seed and run.

So if you're having trouble separating seeding of your app from runnning then this is the best solution I've come up with.